# Google API OAuth-2.0, Installed Application Grant Flow: Why is the authorization code truncated in the browser title?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am encountering behavior inconsistent with Google's documentation on step 2 of this grant flow.

As described at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp , when a "redirect_uri" value of "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" is specified, "your application can then detect that the page has loaded, and can read the title of the HTML page to obtain the authorization code."

With every attempt I have made to use this approach, the result has been the same. After the redirect, the browser's title contains a partial authorization code, though the edit box on the page is correctly populated with the entire authorization code. (I could provide an image for illustration, but not without sufficient "reputation".) Whether I retrieve the title programmatically or just inspect it via the tab's hovertip, the code is consistently truncated at the 44th character of the title, immediately preceding the period in that position in the full code.

With only a partial code, there is no way to proceed past step 2; the documentation leaves little room for doubt that this is buggy behavior. For reference, the full authorization code works if I retrieve it by manual copy and paste (but that is not an option for me in practice).

Has anyone else encountered this behavior?

Most importantly, can Google or a representative thereof, please answer the question of "Why?" (And, assuming it's not something on my end, "When will it be fixed?")

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the shorter code too. The shorter authorization code will work. You can proceed to the next step.